# How to increment a column using DBIx::Class?

Tags: sql, perl, dbix-class

I'm trying to convert some raw DBI calls to DBIx::Class.  I occasionally run across something like:

```
UPDATE 'foo' SET bar = bar + 1 WHERE ...
```

Is there way to do have DBIx::Class execute exactly this kind of query?  I don't want to do something like:

```
$row->update({ bar => $row->bar() + 1 });
```

because there's a race condition there if multiple processes are trying to do the same thing.

I could get around that with some kind of locking at the database level, but that seems worse to me than just using the original query.  Basically I just want to know if there's a clean way of using DBIC to do this or if I should just continue to use raw DBI calls here.

Comment: I assume you meant `$row->{bar}` and not `$row->bar()`

Comment: Increments by 1 is usually for counters.  What kinds of race conditions are you experiencing at this field?

Comment: @TLP I did mean $row->bar() where $row is a DBIC result object.

Comment: @TimothyHa I have a couple of use cases, but to take the counter example, let's say I have several sessions which all want to increment the counter at around the same time. If 2 processes SELECT bar at the same time, they'll both have the value X for that column in the DBIx::Class object.  If they then both increment by one and save the row, after 2 updates the number will only be X + 1, rather X + 2, since both DBIx::Class objects will be incrementing from the same base value (X).

Comment: The closest thing I could find was `$schema->resultset('Widget')->search({ name => 'foo' })->update_all({ count => \'count + 1' })` to add 1 to `count` where `name` is `foo`. This generates two SQL statements, but they're automatically wrapped in a transaction: `SELECT me.id, me.name, me.count FROM test me WHERE ( name = 'foo' )` followed by `UPDATE test SET count = count + 1 WHERE ( id = '1' )`

Comment: @oalders thank you, so your question is valid for any kind of increments, not just by 1.  They're all subject to race conditions

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, that sounds like a reasonable way to do this.  If you want to add that as an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: @oalders I'm not sure it's the best approach. A separate `UPDATE` is generated for each row in the result set. Depending on your database engine, this may or may not be acceptable. With MySQL's InnoDB, for example, transactions are supported and the default transaction isolation level is repeatable read; all reads after the first use the same snapshot, so they won't be affected by later transactions. MySQL's MyISAM, on the other hand, doesn't support transactions, so you would still have a nasty race condition.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot in this case I think it's fine for me.  I'm using Postgres and I only need to update a single row, since the WHERE clause uses a primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the solution from @ThisSuitIsBlackNot's comment but replace `update_all` with `update`:

```
$rs->search(...)->update({
    bar => \'bar + 1',
});
```

This will result in a single UPDATE statement. (Explanation: [`update_all`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#update_all) works by calling `update` on every Row in the ResultSet including things like DBIC triggers, so it has to fetch the rows first. [`update`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#update) on a ResultSet executes a barebones SQL UPDATE.)

Answer (score 0):

Will using DBIx::Class::Storage::TxnScopeGuard help?  You can wrap your block of code in a transaction like this

```
my $guard = $schema->txn_scope_guard;
# your increment
$guard->commit;
```

Comment: In this case it doesn't fully solve the problem occurs at read time as well as write time.  I think the comment by @ThisSuitIsBlackNot is probably the cleanest way to do this.